# c3270 keymap question (enter, newline, backtab, numeric key pad)

Tags: mainframe, zos, 3270

Regarding c3270 what is the general technique to map a newline and an enter key, also a back tab key?  Can the numeric keypad be mapped to function keys?

Answer (score 1):

c3270 has limited key mapping ability.  You can map some keyboards to functions.

For instance, you can map the <kbd>Return</kbd> to be a <kbd>Newline</kbd> by specifying the following sequence in ketmap file like this:

```
<Key>Return: Newline
```

and the Return acts like a Newline on a 3270 but I have not discovered a way to use another modifer like a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

```
Ctrl<Key>Return: Enter
```

Initialization fails with an error `Ctrl modifier is restricted to ASCII-7 printable characters`

And `Shift` is not an acceptable modifier.

You can read more detail here on the [c3270 man page](http://x3270.bgp.nu/Unix/c3270-man.html#Keymaps)

IMHO a full featured emulator is better when you're looking to map to a functional 3270-like experience.